# Advice for suspension 101 for a small ATV robotic platform

Tags: kinematics

I'm a recent grad from mech. eng. program and going into robotics field. I want to design a suspension for a ***small ATV robotic platform on 4 wheels*** that carries max 75 kg load.

I might use the wheels as active crawlers for climbing stairs (not sure) that's why I think a suspension for each wheel is necessary.

Can you please point me in the right direction where to start my research: books, literature, sites.

So far I found some info on the suspension's topic berried deep in robotics books, but I'm hoping that someone would point me to the more precise sources, or the keywords to research, or what field of mechanical design I should re-visit.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Active suspension so probably hydraulics or electrics... plus frequency analysis : hitting the natural frequency of the system is not funny...

Comment: Got it, review of the vibration's course for modeling the suspension system and electronic's for figuring out the motors. 
What about the different configurations of the suspension systems? What field would cover that?

Comment: I'm going to migrate this question to robotics to see if it gets better traction there.